# Python in Execute Process Task

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server, ssis

I have written a python code, then ran it through SSIS in the Execute Process Task.

The code reads and writes to SQL management studio to translate via Google API (pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1), with no output or input through SSIS. the input and output are done through sqlacademy in python.

The codes runs perfectly fine in Jupyter notebook, and I saved it to be .py file, but I face a lot of error in the Execute Process Task in SSIS.

Comment: Talk me through what you've built in python and how the Execute Process Task is configured. Did you use something pyinstaller to convert the .py to an exe? Are you setting the exe as the python or pythonw? If you're using the Argument, make a HelloWorld.py in the same folder and see whether that works. If it does, great then we know it's not permissions, pathing, etc.

Comment: As to your code note having an output, when a process finishes, it returns a value. Assume HelloWorld.py looks like `print("Hello world")` then `python HelloWorld.py` is going to have as a return code zero. Generally, processes in windows return 0 for success, non-zero for error. But that is entire up to the developer of the process. Modify HelloWorld.py to have a second line of `exit(1)`  Now our process is going to run but "error" in SSIS because the assumption it has does not match reality.

Comment: If you know your script works yet returns a 1 as exit value, then you need to right click on the Execute Process Task and select Properties. Find the `SuccessValue` and change that from 0 to 1.

Comment: Your jupyter notebook takes 10 minutes, SSIS finishes in seconds. That sounds suspiciously like that script is bombing out. I would create 2 SSIS Variables called StdOut and StdErr, of type String, and wire that up to the `StandardOutputVariable` and `StandardErrorVariable` I'd then add a Script Task as a successor task. Change the PrecedentConstraint to OnCompletion (success or failure) and add the two Std Variables as ReadOnly and then raise information events to emit the values to the run log https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html Should capture the err

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## HelloWorld.err.py

A trivial python script that will write a string to standard out, another to standard error and the exit with return code 1.

```
import sys
print("Hello world")
print("Egads, something bad happened!", file=sys.stderr)
exit(1)
```

## SSIS package

A sample SSIS package would look something like the following. An Execute Process Task has a successor of a Script Task.

[image]

Double click the precedent constraint (the line between the two) and change that from the default of Success to Completion

[image]

### EPT Python

An Execute Package Task that is configured as shown

[image]

- Executable: C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
- Arguments: C:\ssisdata\SO_75361110.err.py
- StandardOutputVariable: User::StdOut
- StandardErrorVariabele: User::StdErr

### SCR Echo Back

This is a generic Script Task that I use and abuse to dump the values of SSIS Variables to the output log/results tab. It's easy, lightweight and let's you print values without popups or any hard work.

All you need to do is add the Variable(s) in the readonly/readWrite collection. In this case, I selected `User::StdOut` and `User::StdErr`

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_ede4b38a087c4724a71149ffc5ed6be9
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            bool fireAgain = false;
            foreach (Variable item in Dts.Variables)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format("{0}->{1}", item.QualifiedName, item.Value), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

### Results

When my package runs, as "expected" the SuccessValue from my run will be 1 given that I use `exit(1)` from the python script.

Let's see what the Output tab looks like

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SO_Trash\SO_Trash\SO_75361110.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0xC0029151 at EPT Python the thing, Execute Process Task: In Executing "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" "C:\ssisdata\SO_75361110.err.py" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
Task failed: EPT Python the thing
Warning: 0x80019002 at SEQC Do the thing: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back, SCR Echo Back: User::StdErr->Egads, something bad happened!
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back, SCR Echo Back: User::StdOut->Hello world
Warning: 0x80019002 at SO_75361110: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SO_Trash\SO_Trash\SO_75361110.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[68044] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Of note, are these two lines

> Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back, SCR Echo Back: User::StdErr->Egads, something bad happened!

> Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back, SCR Echo Back: User::StdOut->Hello world

That's our Script Task echoing back the value of our Standard Out and Standard Error text streams. My suspicion is that given a "normal" run is 10 minutes and the runs from SSIS are measured in seconds, the process execution is throwing errors to the caller but nobody is listening. This will add a listener and give you better information to diagnose your root cause.